# Read multiple lines from file to a single string

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a file, which lines have specific prefixes. Some kind of data is in multiple lines in some cases, like in this file example:

```
Num: 10101
Name: File_8
Description: qwertz qwertz
qwertz qwertz ztrewq
Quantity: 2
```

Order of properties (num, name, description, quantity) is not defined. I use following code to read data from file and store to array.

```
BufferedReader abc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((strLine = abc.readLine()) != null) {
        if(strLine.startsWith("Name:")){
        data[0] = strLine.substring(strLine.indexOf(" ")+1);
        data[0].trim();
       }
    }
```

Strings between prefixes should be stored in a string.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? The last sentence of your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Skere : I updated question. Example in case of `Description` and `Quantity`: Value of `desc` variable should be `qwertz qwertz qwertz qwertz ztrewq`.

Comment: desc variable???

Comment: @Maurice : I use variable with same name to each properties.

Comment: The word you're looking for is "concatenation".

Comment: @Dominique : Concatenation, but with conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

To capture mappings:

```
String line, key = null, value = null;
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.contains(":")) {
        if (key != null) {
            values.put(key, value.trim());
        }
        int indexOfColon = line.indexOf(":");
        key = line.substring(0, indexOfColon);
        value = line.substring(indexOfColon + 1);
    } else {
        value += " " + line;
    }
}
values.put(key, value.trim());

for (Map.Entry<String, String>  mapEntry: values.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(mapEntry.getKey() + " -> '" + mapEntry.getValue() + "'");
}
```

prints:

```
Description -> 'qwertz qwertz qwertz qwertz ztrewq'
Num -> '10101'
Quantity -> '2'
Name -> 'File_8'
```

Comment: Order of properties(num, name, description, quantity) is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

> Read multiple lines from file to a single string

If you read the content into an array, you can use join:

```
String.join(delimiter, elements);
```

Ex. with delimiter `,` and an array:

```
String str = String.join(",", new String[]{"1st line", "2nd line", "3rd line"});
```

Produces the output:
`1st line,2nd line,3rd line`

---

Or directly read to a string:

```
// assume we have a function
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
return new String(encoded, encoding);
```

Comment: There aren't any predefined delimiters at the end.

Answer (score 0):

ok so everything that is passed to data[0] should be concatenated into a string? Why don't you use StringBuilder class like so?

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader abc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((strLine = abc.readLine()) != null) {
        if(strLine.startsWith("Name:")){
        data[0] = strLine.substring(strLine.indexOf(" ")+1);
        data[0].trim();
        stringBuilder.append(data[0]);
       }
    }
```

Comment: I see, but it is not a solution to read from file multiple lines into single string.